# How do I distinguish negative zero with Aeson?

Tags: haskell, ieee-754, zero, aeson

Haskell distinguishes negative zero:

```
ghci> (isNegativeZero (0 :: Float), isNegativeZero (-0 :: Float))
(False,True)
```

JSON also allows for distinguishing them, since both "0" and "-0" are valid, syntactically.

But Aeson throws away the sign bit:

```
ghci> isNegativeZero <$> eitherDecode "-0"
Right False
```

Why? How can I decode a JSON document while distinguishing non-negative and negative zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in `Data.Aeson` the floating point number is constructed using `Data.Scientific.scientific`

```
scientific :: Integer -> Int -> Scientific
```

> `scientific c e` constructs a scientific number which corresponds to the `Fractional` number: `fromInteger c * 10 ^^ e`.

Since the mantissa is an `Integer`, where we have `0 == -0`, it can not construct a negative zero. Not the best API for constructing special floating point values, it seems.

Perhaps you should file a bug for `aeson`, asking for a workaround in the parser.

Comment: There was [a rather big related discussion](https://github.com/haskell/aeson/issues/546) some time ago.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I see, thanks. It looks way more complicated than I'd have expected.